# originpro 2015 under wine

Tags: wine

I have unsuccesfully tried to install Originpro (data analysis tool) under wine.

The problem is that many libraries (msvcrt110 and others) are missing, hence the software is not bootable.

I have found in literature that wine developers decided not to implement this package.

I just write to figure myself out whether somebody has been able to run Originpro w/out using a virtual machine (i.e. under wine).

Comment: Did you try any of the suggestion from [OginPro's Wine App DB entry](//appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1598)?

Comment: i tried them all, no results... (my version is 2015)